# Swift: angle brackets generics vs some keyword

Tags: swift, generics

I am trying to dive deep into generics in Swift, and while I'm clear on the usage, I am not sure about how things work behind the scenes.

I am watching [Embrace Swift generics](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2022/110352/?time=888) (link leads to relevant section), and they say

> A type using the "some" keyword and a named type parameter in angle
> brackets both declare an opaque type.
>
> **<A: Animal> == some Animal**

In several other places in the video it is expressed that there is no difference between using a named parameter and the some keyword, except for the fact that the first is more expressive.

However, we know that the return value of a function using a typed parameter is determined by the caller, and when using the some keyword it is determined by the function.

[image]

My question is then, if there is no difference, why doesn't the fist function compile, and if there is a difference, what is it?

Thanks

Comment: Post code and errors as text, not images.

Answer (score 1):

The first function basically tries to explicitly specialize a generic function by returning an `Int`. In Swift, generic functions get automatically specialized by type inference.

Think of it in a different way:

An `Int` is not the only `T` that conforms to `Equatable`, e.g. you cannot return an `Int` if `T` was a `String`.

```swift
// The first function can be called by all types that conform to `Equatable`

let value1: Int = someFunc()
let value2: String = someFunc()
```

The second function is not a generic function, it's just a function that returns `some Equatable`.

Answer (score 1):

There are three problems here:

- You are misrepresenting what the video says. The phrase `<A: Animal> == some Animal` never appears, in the narration or onscreen; it's just something you made up (and it's wrong).
- You are not listening to what the video *does* say. The difference between the two sorts of generic is clearly enunciated just before the line that you quote about how they "both declare an opaque type".
- The two methods that you posit in your screenshot are not even parallel to one another, and on top of that the first one is not even meaningful. A formulation with actual parallelism would be:

  ```
  func someFunc<T: Equatable>(_ what: T) -> T {
      return what
  }

  func someFunc2(_ what: some Equatable) -> some Equatable {
      return what
  }
  ```

Moving from the negative to the positive, I'll just repeat what the video tells you about how these constructs differ in their intentions.

Although `some Equatable` can now be used very similarly to `<T: Equatable>`, because it has the (new) ability to be used as a parameter type, its *purpose* is to hide the boxed type *from you, the programmer* behind a protocol name. Thus, the point of

```
func someFunc() -> some Equatable {
    return 1
}
```

is that the *implementation* of the method itself makes it very clear to the compiler that `some Equatable` is Int, and the compiler will enforce this wherever you try to use this value; but it hides that fact from you and from wherever else you use the value. Thus this is illegal:

```
let equ: Int = someFunc() // no
```

But this is legal:

```
let equ: some Equatable = someFunc() // yes
```

The compiler knows that *this* `some Equatable` is Int and will enforce that fact, but also this mode of expression, everywhere it is used. You are *hiding* the Int behind the `some Equatable` and you have to keep hiding it.

On the other hand, a normal generic is *open* as to its type, which is resolved by the *caller*. Thus:

```
func someFunc<T: Equatable>(_ what: T) -> T {
    return what
}
```

Here, the declaration says that the type that comes in as parameter goes out as result, and says *nothing* about what that type is. It is the *caller* who resolves it, by passing something, which resolves T:

```
let i = someFunc(1)
```

Here, T is resolved at compile time to Int, and `i` is resolved at compile time to Int as well, and is so typed, by inference.

If you were to substitute this implementation of `someFunc`:

```
func someFunc(_ what: some Equatable) -> some Equatable {
    return what
}
```

you could still call it in the same way:

```
let i = someFunc(1)
```

but now `i` is typed, as I've already said, as `some Equatable`, and it cannot be typed any other way. `some Equatable` is *opaque* and it remains opaque; the "real" underlying type is hidden from you behind the protocol name.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, just got back to it now. In 15:04 in the video the following is said: 
`A type using the "some" keyword and a named type parameter in angle brackets both declare an opaque type.`